# Access element of array of pointer of structure

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I want to access the element of array of pointer to structure but i have no idea how to access it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
struct hash
{
int pages;
int price;
};
struct hash *h[5]={1,2,3,4,5};//array of pointer to structure
printf("value =%d\n",h->pages);
// want to access and also tell me how to data will be write
}
  How we will access the element I tried it through pointer but it's showing error
```

Comment: this 1. doesn't compile, 2. doesn't make any sense, 3. is incomprehensible and incomplete: "it's showing error" is not even helpful to anybody trying to answer your question.

Comment: 2.5 years of experience in C? o_0

Comment: A pointer of the hash struct must point to either a hash struct or a pointer of a hash struct.  You are setting the pointer values to 1,2,3,4,5 which are just data that could be anywhere in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct hash {
        int pages;
        int price;
    };
    struct hash *h[2];
    h[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct hash));
    h[0]->pages = 1;
    h[0]->price = 2;
    h[1] = malloc(sizeof(struct hash));
    h[1]->pages = 3;
    h[1]->price = 4;
    printf("value = %d\n", h[0]->pages);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample that compiles. Maybe this helps you get started.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct hash
{
int pages;
int price;
};

struct hash h[5]=
{
    { 1, 1 },
    { 2, 2 },
    { 3, 3 },
};

int main(void)
{
    printf("pages: %d\n", h[0].pages);
    printf("pages2: %d\n", h[1].pages);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first suggest trying to get a `stuct hash *h;` to point to a single variable.  Once that works, you should build upon it to get the array of `struct hash *h[5]` to work.